# Is there a standard that describes the term "coplanar waveguide"?

Tags: terminology, waveguide

I look at [IEC60050](https://electropedia.org/) "*International Electrotechnical Vocabulary*" standard at [section 726](https://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/index?openform&part=726) "*Transmission lines and waveguides*" and searching on the word "coplanar" gives me no matches. Is there a standard that describes the terms "*coplanar waveguide*", "*coplanar waveguide with ground*" and "*grounded coplanar waveguide*"?

P.S. I know what is the "*coplanar waveguide*" and other terms. There is a good picture and description [here](https://www.nwengineeringllc.com/article/coplanar-waveguide-design-for-your-rf-pcb.php). I whant to know these terms are the standard terms or just the common terms.

Comment: No standard that I know of. But it is commonly used in textbooks about RF design and waveguides.